# Anyone installed GNU Debian root sucessfully on a Kindle? (without rooting)

Tags: debian, android, gnuroot

My goal is to be able to compile java programs on my Kindle. I have installed GNU Debian root on a Samsung S7 and then subsequently installed default-jdk. This didn't involve rooting the device. I was able to get the app (GNURoot Debian) from google play store and downloaded jdk from the terminal emulator (apt-get install default-jdk)
I am now able compile java source code and wanted to do the same on my Kindle. I don't want to have to root the device or even install play store on the kindle necessarily.

Has anyone tried to do this on a Kindle? 
I have tried downloading the apk file from http://kindleapk.com/GNURoot.html
The installation looks slightly different I am prompted to create Rootfs for one of the following distro's
wheezy
gentoo
fedora
aboriginal
wheezyx

when you try to do this you are naturally directed to download the file from amazon apps store which is completely useless for this sort of thing.
I think I may have the wrong apk,just need to install GNU Debian root really.
Anyone had much luck with this?

New to GNULinux and loving it.
I'm beginning to understand why people have a passionate contempt for microsoft windows. In terms of user experience with windows, I feel cheated. People are paying for poor quality, I don't get how that's been working for so long